# How can I get this ui.bootstrap.datepicker to work in jsfiddle?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

I'm trying to get the ui.bootstrap.datepicker control found at http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap to work in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/oqo2xv3e/7

I've reduced the HTML down to one input and button:

```
<div ng-app="mainApp">
    <div ng-controller="mainController">  
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div>[{{message}}]</div>

            <input type="text" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="status.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" class="bootstrapdatepicker" />

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="fa fa-calendar-plus-o"></i></button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The button click calls `open()` and sends $event but doesn't open the calendar, nor does it show me any errors in Firebug:

```
angular.module('mainApp', []).controller('mainController', function($scope) {

    $scope.message = 'angular is working';

    $scope.today = function() {
        $scope.dt = new Date();
    };
    $scope.today();

    $scope.clear = function () {
        $scope.dt = null;
    };

    // Disable weekend selection
    $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
        return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) );
    };

    //MIN AND MAX DATES
    $scope.toggleMin = function() {
        $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
    };
    $scope.toggleMin();
    $scope.maxDate = new Date(2020, 5, 22);

    $scope.open = function($event) {
        $scope.status.opened = true;
    };

    $scope.dateOptions = {
        formatYear: 'yy',
        startingDay: 1
    };

    $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
    $scope.format = $scope.formats[1];

    $scope.status = {
        opened: false
    };

    var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
    var afterTomorrow = new Date();
    afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 2);
    $scope.events =
        [
        {
            date: tomorrow,
            status: 'full'
        },
        {
            date: afterTomorrow,
            status: 'partially'
        }
    ];

  $scope.getDayClass = function(date, mode) {
    if (mode === 'day') {
      var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

      for (var i=0;i<$scope.events.length;i++){
        var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

        if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
          return $scope.events[i].status;
        }
      }
    }

    return '';
  };
});
```

**What else do I have to do to get this calendar control working?**

Comment: Your jsfiddle uses angular 1.1.1, which is completely obsolete, and doesn't have angular ui bootstrap at all in its list of resources.

Comment: Beside what @JB Nizet mentioned, you also have to have the 'ui.bootstrap' when you create your angularjs application:
angular.module('mainApp', [ 'ui.bootstrap']); and the external resource should point to ui-bootstrap-tpls file which is the bootstrap library to be used with angularjs.

Comment: ok, I've got Angular 1.2.1 and 8 resources and am get a Firebug error now "Error: ngModel.$validators is undefined" which is not something directly in my code but has to do with some dependency that is not present I suspect, any ideas what could be causing this error? http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/oqo2xv3e/8/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the angular js code in the external resources

`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js`

I've tried that and running the example i get a console error (which i frankly don't know how to debug):

`TypeError: window.angular.$$csp is not a function`

But the good news is that Angular seems to work in JsFiddle. Hope it helps.